# How to proxy my React frontend to my Node backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to concurrently run my React frontend with my Node backend but I keep getting this error. I have have search online for a solution but I haven't gotten any clear answer. How can I solve this issue?

```
(node:10084) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[1] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[1] (node:10084) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option. 


const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


// data parsing
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.post('/contact', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
 console.log(req.body)
 res.render('contact', {qs: req.query});

   let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
     service: 'gmail',
     auth: {
       user: 'bojurier@gmail.com', // generated ethereal user
       pass: process.env.EMAIL_SECRET_PASS // generated ethereal password
     },
     
 });
 const mailOption = {
   name: req.body.name,
   from: req.body.email,
   to: 'bojurier@gmail.com',
   text: req.body.message

 }
 transporter.sendMail(mailOption, (error, info) =>{
   if(error){
     console.log(error)
     res.send('error')
   } else {
     console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response)
     res.send('Success')
   }
 })
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: Look into your project Webpack config file  and replace `onAfterSetupMiddleware ` by `setupMiddlewares `

Comment: could you please show us some of your server code. Also it would be nice to know your folder structure and how you are running your react frontend and your express backend.

Comment: I have update my code with my server side code. also as for my structure, I have all my file on the same level.

Comment: @lissettdm I have tried it but I am stuck. it has been days and this is driving me crazy lol. Any more ideas?